# How to use bootstrap ScrollSpy with anchor using dots?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

### Context

In the development of the pydata-sphinx-theme we use extensively twitter bootstrap to build the UI of a Sphinx generated documentation. When documenting Python API, the Autodoc plugin (that reads the Python docstring and transform it into a documentation page) creates anchors for functions that correspond to the exact path f the method: "pandas.DataFrame.from_csv". These points seems to be incompatible with the twitter bootstrap ScrollSpy tool as they are not interpreted as correct anchors.

For interested reader, see this thread for more context: https://github.com/pydata/pydata-sphinx-theme/issues/1435

### reproducible example

I created this small fiddle by adapting one of bootstrap example: https://codepen.io/12rambau/pen/rNovoyw

```html
<div id="container" class="row">
  <div id="list-example" class="list-group col-4">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#item.1">Item 1</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#item.2">Item2</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#item.3">Item 3</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#item.4">Item 4</a>
  </div>
  <div class=col-8>
    <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#list-example" data-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example">
      <h4 id="item.1">Item 1</h4>
      <p> ... </p>
      <h4 id="item.2">Item 2</h4>
      <p> ...</p>
      <h4 id="item.3">Item 3</h4>
      <p> ... </p>
      <h4 id="item.4">Item 4</h4>
      <p> ... </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see it's simply not working as I replaced the target names by "item.1" instead of "item 1".

Can someone explain me why it is not working ?
Is there a workaraound or will I be forced to code a custom scrollspy function ?